# Need help printing out values correctly without repeating them in java

Tags: java

I have a program where a user enters the size of the card set from 1 to 52 and the x amount cards need to be printed when printSet() is called. After that bubbleSort() is called to sort the values and the printSet() is called again to print the values with suits but Jack, Queen, King and Ace seem to get replaced by a number and the interesting part is that not all of them gets changed to a number and sometimes they print perfectly. And when the size of the card set increases to lets say 52 then the values and suits repeat when printing.

Here is an example to demonstrate the problems:

The Jack, Queen, King & Ace problem:

input (size of cardset): 10

output:

(when printSet is called the first time):

```
You Picked: 10 of Hearts
You Picked: 6 of Diamonds
You Picked: 3 of Spades
You Picked: 7 of Clubs
You Picked: Jack of Clubs
You Picked: Ace of Spades
You Picked: Ace of Clubs
You Picked: Jack of Clubs
You Picked: 6 of Spades
You Picked: King of Hearts
```

(when printSet is called the second time):

```
You Picked: 10 of Hearts
You Picked: 6 of Diamonds
You Picked: 3 of Spades
You Picked: 7 of Clubs
You Picked: 0 of Clubs
You Picked: Ace of Spades
You Picked: Ace of Clubs
You Picked: 0 of Clubs
You Picked: 6 of Spades
You Picked: 2 of Hearts
```

The values and suits repeating problem:

input (size of cardset): 52

```
You Picked: 10 of Hearts
You Picked: 10 of Hearts
You Picked: 3 of Spades
You Picked: 7 of Clubs
You Picked: 7 of Clubs
You Picked: Ace of Spades
You Picked: Ace of Clubs
You Picked: 0 of Clubs
You Picked: 6 of Spades
You Picked: 2 of Hearts
...
```

So my main code for the part of the problem I am facing with is the following:

```
    public CardSet(int howMany){
        PlayingCard = new PlayingCard[howMany];
        startCount = howMany;
        Random rand = new Random();
        int count;
        for(count = 0; count < PlayingCard.length; count++){
            int x = rand.nextInt(13) + 1;
            int y = rand.nextInt(4) + 0;
            PlayingCard[count] = new PlayingCard(y, x);
            PlayingCard pc = new PlayingCard();

        }
    }

    public void printSet(){
        System.out.println("\t-------------------------");
        for(int i = 0; i < PlayingCard.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(PlayingCard[i]);
        }
    }
```

Here is the full code of the program, CardSet.java is where I updated the code.

CardSet.java

```
import java.util.*;

public class CardSet{
    private PlayingCard[] PlayingCard;
    int startCount;
    private Random rand;

    public CardSet(int howMany){
        PlayingCard = new PlayingCard[howMany];
        startCount = howMany;
        Random rand = new Random();
        int count;
        for(count = 0; count < PlayingCard.length; count++){
            int x = rand.nextInt(13) + 1;
            int y = rand.nextInt(4) + 0;
            PlayingCard[count] = new PlayingCard(y, x);
            PlayingCard pc = new PlayingCard();

        }
    }

    public void printSet(){
        System.out.println("\t-----");
        for(int i = 0; i < PlayingCard.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(PlayingCard[i]);
        }
    }

    public void bubbleSort(){
        PlayingCard _pc = new PlayingCard();
        /*
        for(int i = 1; i < PlayingCard.length; i++){
            for(int j = PlayingCard.length - 1; j >= i; j--){
                if(PlayingCard[j - 1].getValue() > (PlayingCard[j].getValue())){
                    _pc = PlayingCard[j - 1];
                    PlayingCard[j - 1] = PlayingCard[j];
                    PlayingCard[j] = _pc;
                }
            }
        }
        */
    }
}
```

PlayingCard.java

```
public class PlayingCard {
    String suit;
    private int value;
    public static final String Suits[] = {"Hearts", "Clubs", "Diamonds", "Spades"};
    public static final String face_suits[] = {"Jack", "Queen", "King", "Ace"};
    public static final int values[] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14};

    PlayingCard(){
        suit = "";
        value = 0;
    }
    PlayingCard(String aSuit, int aValue){
            this.suit = aSuit;
            this.value = aValue;
    }

    PlayingCard(int aSuit, int aValue){
        suit = Suits[aSuit];
        value = aValue;
    }

    public void setValue(int aValue){
        value = aValue;
    }

    public void setSuit(String aSuit){
        suit = aSuit;
    }

    public int getValue(){
        return this.value;
    }

    public String getSuit(){
        return this.suit;
    }

    public String toString(){
        if(value == 1){
            String sValue = face_suits[3];
            return "\tYou Picked: " + sValue + " of " + suit;
        }
        if (value > 10){
            value = value - 11;
            String sValue = face_suits[value];
            return "\tYou Picked: " + sValue + " of " + suit;
        } else{
            return "\tYou Picked: " + value + " of " + suit;
        }
    }

    public boolean equals(PlayingCard aCard) {
        return (this.suit.equals(aCard.suit)
        && this.value == aCard.value)? true : false;
    }
}
```

AlmostGame.java

```
/* ---------------------------------------------
    Modify the PlayingCard class and write the 
    CardSet class that will allow the 
    AlmostGame demo class to deal a user-specified
    number of unduplicated cards
    
    Use the class diagram below (new method as marked):
    ----------------------------------------
        PlayingCard
    ----------------------------------------
    - suit : String
    - value : int   
    ----------------------------------------
    + PlayingCard()
    + PlayingCard(aSuit : String, aValue : int)
NEW + PlayingCard(aSuit : int, aValue : int)
    + getSuit() : String
    + getValue() : int
    + setSuit(aSuit:String) : void
    + setValue(aValue:int) : void
    + toString() : String
NEW + equals(aCard : PlayingCard) : boolean
    ----------------------------------------

    --------------------------
NEW     CardSet
    ---------------------------
    - set : PlayingCard[]
    - startCount : int
    - rand_ : Random  (static member, can't underline here)
    ---------------------------
    + CardSet(howMany : int)
    + printSet() : void
    + bubbleSort() : void
    ---------------------------
    
    You should not alter the AlmostGame class (this one)
    
------------------------------------------------ */

import java.util.*;
/**
 * A class that randomly creates a CardSetof unduplicated PlayingCards,
 * prints the set, sorts the set and prints it again
 * @author CSC251
 */
public class AlmostGame
{
    /**
     * This method runs the AlmostGame class
     * @param args unused
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = 0;
        while(size >52 || size < 1)
        {
            System.out.print("\nEnter size of cardset (between 1 and 52): ");
            size = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
        }
        CardSet hand1 = new CardSet(size);
        hand1.printSet();
        hand1.bubbleSort();
        hand1.printSet();
        System.out.println("\nThanks for playing...\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post your code here and provide relevant details about your issue.

Comment: For example, if you enter 2, how many cards should you get?

Comment: Please do not provide a link to your code, especially one that requires an E-Mail address and Password to view it. Place the pertinent code with the problem in your post.

Comment: I have updated the question now with code

Comment: @DevilsHnd sorry about that, I shared a link to the code just incase it was needed but thought the invite link would not require email & password to view it, I have updated the link and tested it and can say that it does not require email & password to view it

Comment: @NomadMaker you should get 2 cards.

Comment: You should edit the question with this information. Comments can be deleted and some people don't read them.

Comment: @NomadMaker Okay thank you for telling me that, I have updated the question with the information

Comment: I want to help but i'm not understanding what your program is supposed to do.

Comment: @Jore I just updated my question so hopefully it clears up everything, its a card program where you need to enter how many cards you want and it will print the cards with values and suits normally and then will sort it using bubble sort and will print it again but in an order

Comment: Please paste you entire code, or better yet a [mre], into the question as text.

Comment: @NomadMaker Okay I have pasted the code entire code. The minimal reproducible example is to run the code and enter a card set size greater then or equal to 4 but less then or equal to 52

Comment: In the constructor for CardSet, why do you create and throw away a blank card (``PlayingCard pc = new PlayingCard();``)

Comment: To be honest I don't remember why I put it there